# Encoding CSV File With arabic content

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I've tried to import csv file into mysql table and everything is Ok but I get a problem with Encoding the content of the file, the content is in "arabic Content."
The following image explains my problem:

1- this is my CSV FILE
[image: CSV FILE With Arabic Content]

2-My PHP code:

```
    $c=1;

while($data=fgetcsv($file,1000,","))
{
    if($c==1)
    {
        $c++;
        continue;

    }
$row=explode(";",$data[0]);
foreach($row as $val)
{
    echo $val."&nbsp;";
}
echo "<br>";
$c++;
}
```

3- The Result:

[image: The Content After Display it]
    I try to insert data in mysql table

4- If I insert these data into Mysql Table, it will be :

[image: the data in database]

I'm thankful for any help,

Thanks

Comment: You need to me sure your table character sets if one off the utf8 types.. and you have to make sure php connects to the database with utf8 charset.

Comment: thanks but not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your CSV file in UTF-8 or process your string using [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php).
Make sure your MySQL table is also in UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

```
/open file pointer to standard output
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
```

//add BOM to fix UTF-8 in Excel

```
fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers but the solution is:

1. open CVS file in any editor
2. re-save it with UTF-8 encoding and CVS extension
3. and upload it by an script